# Initial values of creation/annihilation operators

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, quantum-electrodynamics, time-evolution, second-quantization

I have a question about creation/annihilation operators. For example, if I have an evolution equation for annihilation operator of photon
$$ \frac{da_k}{dt} = -i \omega_k a_k$$
I obviously obtain
$$a_k(t) = a_k(0) e^{-i \omega_kt} $$
I not fully understand how to find initial value of $a_k$. Should we just find it from expression of canonical variables $P_k$ and $Q_k$  or maybe I should go to Schrodinger representation since $a_k(0)$ does not depend on time? 
Or there is another way?

Comment: If you are working in the interaction picture, I think the initial value will be the Schrodinger picture operator, i.e. $a_{\mbox{int}}\left(t=t_0\right)=a_{\mbox{Schr\"od}}$

Comment: @Cryo OP is clearly doing free QFT in Heisenberg picture, as the equations in their question suggest.

Comment: these are operators. $a_k(0)=a_k$ and  we define that as $a_k|vac>=0$

Answer (score 1):

$a$ is an operator. There isn't a specific value to it, and even if you do provide a certain expression in the matrix form – it won't give you much information, as the expression entirely depends on the choice of the basis.

One example would be the generalization of the standard matrix form of the oscillator's lowering operator in the energy eigenstate basis:

$$ a \left| n \right> = \sqrt{n} \left| n - 1 \right>, $$

or

$$ a=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{2} & 0 & \dots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{3} & \dots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots
\end{array}\right). $$

I trust you to do the obvious QFT generalization of this.

But this explicit expression won't actually give you much. In fact, all information is already encoded in the algebra of $a_{\bf p}$ and $a^{\dagger}_{\bf p}$.

The reason is – there's the Stone-von Neumann theorem that guarantees that there's a single unique representation of the algebra on the Hilbert space. So specifying an explicit expression of $a$ is equivalent to specifying a basis on the Hilbert space.

That is almost true for the case of QFT – the caveat being that the vacuum $\left| 0 \right>$ must lie in the Hilbert space.

Comment: Yes, operators $a_k$ and $a_k^\dagger$  can't tell me a lot, but opeartor $n_k = a_k^\dagger a_k$ can. Should I just combine the equations of motion for creation/annihilation operators to obtain the equations for occupation number, which can show me dynamic of the system? I think it also possible to find initial value of it.

Comment: @Kirill no, the matrix form of the number operator also doesn’t tell you anything. It is the spectrum that is physically meaningful — and you can obtain the spectrum of the number operator directly from CCR, no explicit form of $a$ or $a^{\dagger}$ required.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus That's not correct, the spectrum only gives you the outcomes of measurements, but the “matrix elements” (computed with respect to a basis) give you the statistics and when these outcomes occur. Specifying your initial value (which is an operator here) with respect to one particular basis suffices and uniquely fixes your operator. Also, your comment about the vacuum is backwards: you need to *define* a vacuum state, which in some applications could be a thermal state or the Fermi projection. From then you then construct the relevant Fock space.

Comment: @MaxLein very well then give me an example of a physical observable for which knowing the CCR isn’t enough to calculate it.

Comment: Example 1: Consider $a$ and $a^{\dagger}$ on Fock spaces with inequivalent vacua. Example 2: Consider a quantum particle on the real line on the one hand and on the interval $[0,L]$ on the other. In both cases, position and momentum operator have the same commutation relations. Thus, $a = q - \mathrm{i} p$ and $a^{\dagger} = q + \mathrm{i} p$ have the same commutation relations. Example 3: Consider quantum particles on $[0,L]$, but pick hamiltonians with different boundary conditions. Knowing your commutation relations is not enough.

Comment: @MaxLein oh sure, if you’re working with 2 different Hilbert spaces — you’ll get different results. The free QFT Hilbert space is uniquely generated from the vacuum though — thus my remark that given the vacuum vector we can reconstruct the entire Hilbert space. The matrix expression of $a$ in that Hilbert space doesn’t matter at all, because it entirely depends on the choice of the basis. My answer doesn’t apply to all systems you can imagine — just to free QFT.

Comment: 1/2 Your claim was very specific: that you could calculate the spectrum solely from the commutation relations, which you can't. All Fock spaces (i. e. the relevant Hilbert space) are constructed from a vacuum state, independently of whether you are considering the field theory is free or not. Creation and annihilation operators are independent of the hamiltonian you consider! Hence, my third example, where you evolve $a$ and $a^{\dagger}$ with the dynamics generated by two distinct hamiltonians. This does not change the spectrum (the time evolution is unitary),

Comment: 2/2 but completely changes the predictions of outcomes (i. e. the statistics). These cannot be computed from the CCR alone as you have claimed. 

You are also wrong about basis-dependent expressions: operators such as momentum or angular momentum are defined in a particular basis. Basis-dependent expressions are not bad or invalid, you just need to keep track of the basis.

Comment: @MaxLein no, I specifically mentioned that the vacuum state is also important in QFT in my answer. You are misinterpreting it — the first part talks about a specific model (oscillator), but then I mention that the same applies to QFT with a caveat. Also, this only applies to free QFT. However, interacting QFT could be built from the vacuum rather similarly (provided that Wightman functions are known, which is not true for realistic models in 4d)

Comment: Once you add enough restrictions, we are left with the harmonic oscillator ;) You mention that the “vacuum state is important in QFT”, but you fail to see *in what way* it is important. Hence my example with inequivalent vacua — yes, they are defined on different Fock spaces, but that is the point. This has nothing to do with interactions (i. e. whether you are considering a free QFT), because we haven't specified a hamiltonian yet. In general, CCRs are not enough to fix your operators up to unitary equivalence.

Comment: @MaxLein my last sentence should be interpreted as “if the vacua of all harmonic oscillators is in the Hilbert space, then there’s a unique Hilbert space generated by fields acting on it”. Your examples of “inequivalent vacua” are *not* oscillator vacua (e.g. the state with all occupation numbers equal to 1 is lorentz inv etc but isn’t the vacua for any of the oscillator constituents).

Comment: Once you fix your Hilbert space, you *have* fixed your vacuum. When you start with an abstract CCR or CAR algebra, you can have inequivalent representations of this abstract algebra on a Hilbert space. The (anti)commutation relations are fixed on the level of the algebra, but many physical properties depend on the representation. (One example from solid state physics is the algebra generated by magnetic translations on the torus; depending on the flux, these can have inequivalent representations.) And I don't think the restrictions you impose are neither necessary nor sufficient.

Comment: @MaxLein again, my answer doesn’t apply to all known physical systems. I start with an oscillator, so please tell me if you know a unitarily inequivalent realization of the CCR of the oscillator, because the absence of thereof is the subject of the Stone-von Neumann theorem. Then I say that the same is true in free QFT as long as you postulate that the vacuum of each constituent oscillator is the chosen vacuum state of the QFT, and is thus in the chosen Hilbert space. Do you disagree with this, or do you just like to argue? :)

Comment: I gave you a concrete example in my last post that comes from condensed matter physics concerning the so-called Hofstadter and the Harper model. You can understand both as models arising from *inequivalent representations* of the non-commutative torus generated by magnetic translations. While the hamiltonians are isospectral, both models have different Quantum Hall Conductivities and therefore you can indeed measure directly what representation class your experimental setup belongs to. You can find more info in [Chapter 2.4–2.6](https://gdenittis.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/phd_thesis.pdf).

Comment: @MaxLein I don’t disagree with you! In general, the choice of the Hilbert space matters! But your example is not equivalent to an oscillator, nor to the free QFT.

Comment: Because my argument starts with an algebra, not a specific hamiltonian, my claim holds for *any* hamiltonian that is the representation of some element of the abstract $C^*$-algebra. Secondly, [you can indeed express such periodic hamiltonians as a sum of oscillators](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~sunkai/teaching/Fall_2014/Chapter6.pdf). In fact, once you diagonalize these hamiltonians, you get exactly one oscillator per energy band (cf. equation (6.16) in the reference).

Comment: @MaxLein I fail to see any relation to the original question whatsoever. What are you claiming, exactly? Initial conditions != representation, OP has a differential equation where $a(t)$ is *already* in some representation, and they want the initial conditions on $a(0)$ (unless I misunderstood the question). My answer is that the matrix form of $a(0)$ doesn’t matter. Then I mention that if there were two unitarily inequivalent choices, we’d have two unitarily inequivalent representations of the Weyl algebra, which is in contradiction with a theorem.

Comment: @MaxLein you don’t seem to argue with any of that points. Instead, you argue that other $C^*$ algebras admit inequivalent representations, which I happily agree with. I don’t like arguing about nothing, and therefore I will not reply to you any longer because I don’t see any purpose in such. No hard feelings, I hope. P.S. thank you for your references, I don’t have time now to dive into condensed matter stuff, but I’m hoping some day to learn at least the basics of it.

Comment: No offense taken. The Stone-von Neumann theorem that you quote shows the uniqueness of the representation on $\mathbb{R}$, and by extension to $\mathbb{R}^d$. But it does *not* hold on the torus as the example I gave shows: you can have identically looking hamiltonians whose creation and annihilation operators satisfy the exact same commutation relations, but which produce different physics. Since the original example contains $k$ as an index, it seems that the OP makes reference to a problem from condensed matter physics where $k$ is an element of the Brillouin zone (which is a torus).

Comment: @MaxLein I've left for some days and missed such an interesting conversation, But at the same time I feel a little bit confused. What I finally have to do to find dynamic of my system, i.e. occupation number (not an operator) of modes/harmonics? I gave a simple example of evolution equation, you can consider it as evolution of annih. operator of photon; this expression will obviously look more complicated since my radiation interacts with other particles or exitations (with phonons for example).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not very specific here. Let me try to infer as much as I can, and then you need to correct me. You are working in the Heisenberg picture here. That means your state is independent of time but you time-evolve your observable instead. Your notation suggests that you are considering a periodic problem with a single band of frequency $\omega_k$ (as there is no band index). $a_k$ annihilates one oscillator mode and $a_k^{\dagger}$ creates one. $k$ could be an element of the Brillouin torus or of the continuum, it is not clear which.

You mention that this is the evolution equation of a photon. That means you already have a universally accepted definition for creation and annihilation operators (one for each polarization in fact), and these satisfy commutation relations with a transverse delta function. So you are already given $a_k(0)$, and this is the thing that you plug in. In the absence of interactions, the number of photons is conserved, so the evolution equation will look like the one you suggested. Once you add interaction, then this will evidently be no longer true.

You will be able to find more details in chapter 13 of Herbert Spohn's book *Dynamics of Charged Particles and Their Radiation Field*.

Comment: I'll try to be more specific: e.g., I'd refer you to Yariv's paper _Quantum theory for parametric interactions of light and hypersound_. We have $a^\dagger_j, a_j$ operators for photons, where _j_ relates to specfic mode of laser radiation. Also there are $a^\dagger_k, a_k$ for phonons, where _k_ represent harmonic in Fourier series of acoustic field. In case of interaction we find that each modes are coupled and also there are incredibly large number of it (luckily we don't need all of them). How can I get the occupation number of my mode if I know evolution of occupation number _operator_?

Answer (score -1):

$a_k(0)$ is set by initial conditions, independent of the differential equation you have provided. It could be any normal operator.